# Bug: Crystal Report Viewer "document is being processed" modal dialog is not getting closed on HTTP Error

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal Reports Viewer for ASP.Net:

We have come across a situation where **"Please wait while the document is being processed."** modal dialog is not getting closed when HTTP Request has failed.

**Development Environment:**

- ASP.Net with Target Framework 4.6.1
- Crystal Report 13.0.2000.0, Version: 13.0.19.2312
- Database Oracle
- IIS Server

**Problem:**

It was found many time that on navigation of pages or while report is being loaded, Crystal Report Viewer shows a modal dialog with message **"Please wait while the document is being processed."**. Said message will disappear on successful request from the server, but in many case like, Network failed, Server responded with HTTP error code or in any case where ajax request has failed to execute it, in such case this modal dialog box does not get closed and due to this user keep waiting to disappear this dialog but nothing happens, and user can not navigate, they will be forced to refresh the page or reopen the report.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Run the report in browser
2. Possibly keep the data of two - three page so that you can navigate
3. Once report is loaded, Stop the IIS Server, so that when you press
   next page, it can generate a HTTP Error
4. if you see network log in Debug mode, request has already failed and
   returned but, "Please wait while the document is being processed."
   dialog is still executing and user can not navigate in the report
   due to modal view. Actually, It should have informed user that last request has failed and you should try again.

Please see the screenshot for reference:

[image: screenshot]

[I have posted this question to SAP Forum but yet to get the answer](https://answers.sap.com/questions/130146/crystal-report-viewer-for-net-document-is-being-pr.html)

I have tried to manage this using window.onerror and hiding the modal window, Is there any better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Mine was taking forever in postbacks when I clicked any button of CRV. I guessed the viewer must be waiting for parameters in the background. So I re-used the parameters as follows:

```
this.crvMain.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. In my code, I found a refresh statement that was freezing the report, preventing it from being loaded. If I comment out this refresh, the report works correctly.